# Transpiled GraphQL with Babel is throwing error "Cannot call class as function"

Tags: express, graphql, babeljs

I am trying to get running GraphQL server. I have simple schema in GraphQL

```
import {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLSchema
} from 'graphql'
import db from './models'

const user = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "user",
  description: 'This represents a user',
  fields: () => {
    return {
        id: {
            type: GraphQLInt,
            resolve(user) {
                return user.id
            }
        },
        firstName: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resole(user) {
                return user.firstName
            }
        },
        lastName: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resole(user) {
                return user.lastName
            }
        },
        email: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resole(user) {
                return user.email
            }
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resole(user) {
                return user.createdAt
            }
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resole(user) => {
                return user.updatedAt
            }
        }
      }
     }
 })


 const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
   name: 'Query',
   description: 'This is root Query',
   fields: () => {
      return {
        users: {
            type: GraphQLList(user),
            args: {
                id: {
                    type: GraphQLInt
                },
                email: {
                    type: GraphQLString
                }
            },
            resolve(root, args) {
                return db.user.findAll({where: args})
            }
          }
       }
    }
 })

 const Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: Query
 })

 export default Schema
```

I am transpile it with babel into ES5, but every time when I try run it with express

```
import GraphHTTP from 'express-graphql'
import Schema from './schema'

app.use('/grapql', GraphHTTP({
  schema: Schema,
  pretty: true,
  graphiql: true
}))
```

I am getting this error

```
 \node_modules\graphql\type\definition.js:41
 function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }                                                             
TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

I check it again and again if i have some typing error but i didnt find enything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of `type: GraphQLList(user)` use `type: new GraphQLList(user)`

`GraphQLList` is a `class` and you have to create it's instance and use, but you have called it as a function.

```
 const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
   name: 'Query',
   description: 'This is root Query',
   fields: () => {
      return {
        users: {
            type: new GraphQLList(user),   
            args: {
                id: {
                    type: GraphQLInt
                },
                email: {
                    type: GraphQLString
                }
            },
            resolve(root, args) {
                return db.user.findAll({where: args})
            }
          }
       }
    }
 })
```